# Kafka start issue with Windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run Kafka on my windows machine and i get the below exception.

```
C:\Users\Abdul.Qaadir\Desktop\Camunda\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>.\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
**The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

C:\Users\Abdul.Qaadir\Desktop\Camunda\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\bin\windows>java -version
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63MzJ.png)

Comment: This seems issue with windows behaviour with bat files. Nothing related to Kafka. Search for this error message and you will get lot of hints.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem in windows too.

As a workaround, unzip kafka in a folder with a shorter name,like C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\Camunda\Kafka\

You must have the bin, lib, ... folders right there.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

It was due to directory depth. Moved the kafka installable under c drive and it worked.